# Subscribe to events using local geth in light mode?

Tags: go-ethereum, events, golang, websocket

I've followed this [guide](https://goethereumbook.org/block-subscribe/) to subscribe to events. I succesfully subscribed to the new block headers using Infura provider. But when I try to use local geth node syncing in light mode, it connects, but can't receive new events. Waits for a while, and then throws with `unexpected EOF`.

I think it's impossible to subscribe to the new events using the node in light mode, but I can't find any information to proove this. Is it right?

Answer (score 2):

No, my suggestion was wrong, the problem is different. I did the same steps, but with web3.js and it worked out.

UPD: So, after updating the go package `go-ethereum` to v1.9.2, everything works perfectly.

Solution:

```
go get -u github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum
```